# Is there a trace or troubleshooting plugin for Raphael?

Tags: trace, raphael

I'm new to Raphael and exploring some of the animation features. I'd like to get trace info of, for example, **animateAlong()** at each stage of animation.

I've setup my own trace canvas object that I can put messages in which helps, but I'm sure someone must have created a trace plugin that's better than my attempt. I've searched but not found anything.

Much appreciate any help.

Leon

Answer (score 0):

I've realised that I can manage with my own trace mechanism. Here's the Raphael:

```
var traceX = 5;
var traceY = 5;
var tracer = Raphael("trace");
function T(s) {
    traceY+=10;
    tracer.text(traceX,traceY,s).attr({
        'text-anchor': 'start'
    });
} // T()
T("TRACE");
```

// subsequent calls take the form:
 T(s); // where s is the message

here's the HTML:
<div id="trace"></div>

and here's the css:
trace {
    background-color: #cdc;
    border: double 2px blue;
    height: 5000px;
    width: 300px;
    position: relativee;
    margin: 0;
}